# Why does the connection between the restaurant and the castle break?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix-reloaded

In Matrix Reloaded (2003), Merovingian and company leave the way they came, closing the door behind them and when Neo re-opens the door he finds himself high up in the mountains. The Merovingian not a keymaker, then how did he break the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Merovingian is not the key maker. He had sequestered the key maker, and likely forced the key maker to give him a key that does what happened. The Merovingian used a key to escape, and the key only works for the one instance the door is opened with that key. Once the door is closed, it resets to its original connection.